# Create a pedigree in R when only 1 parent is known for some individuals?

Tags: r, error-handling

Is there a way to create a pedigree in R when only 1 parent is known for some individuals?

I've tried using kinship2 package in R to create a pedigree but I believe this can only handle when either no parents are known (considered generation 1) and then both parents are known thereafter.

I believe synbreed package is able to deal with this and I have tried the code below but for some reason I receive an error code that I cannot decipher. Is there something wrong with the way my data are structured? Or how I have formulated the arguments of create.pedigree() function? Or is it not possible to construct this pedigree in synbreed package?

Note rows 5 and 6 of data frame 'Ped' which have only one parent ID.

```
> Ped<-read.csv("Pedigree.csv",header=T)
> library(synbreed)

> head(Ped)
  IndividualID    SireID     DamID    Sex
1    019-35751 026-34118 026-34117   male
2    019-35740      <NA>      <NA> female
3    019-35791 026-34129 026-34128   male
4    019-35702      <NA>      <NA>   male
5    019-35784      <NA> 026-34147 female
6    019-35764      <NA> 026-34133   male

> str(Ped)
'data.frame':   1136 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ IndividualID: Factor w/ 1136 levels "019-35702","019-35712",..: 6 4 10 1 9 8 3 63 62 108 ...
 $ SireID      : Factor w/ 136 levels "019-35712","019-35756",..: 8 NA 15 NA NA NA 23 23 23 84 ...
 $ DamID       : Factor w/ 131 levels "026-34101","026-34103",..: 4 NA 7 NA 13 8 NA NA NA 30 ...
 $ Sex         : Factor w/ 2 levels "female","male": 2 1 2 2 1 2 2 2 2 2 ...

> create.pedigree(Ped$IndividualID, Ped$SireID, Ped$DamID , unknown = NA)
Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, is.na(pedigree), value = 0) : 
  unsupported matrix index in replacement
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know the `synbreed` package and the assumptions it makes about individuals with only one known parent, so the answer below may be different from what you are looking for.

However, if you know/believe that the unknown parents refer to independent individuals then you can "fix" your dataset by adding "empty" parents.

A toy dataset that resembles what you show could be

```
fid id father mother sex
1   1   .      .      1
1   2   .      .      2
1   3   1      2      1
1   4   1      2      1
1   5   .      2      2
1   6   .      2      1
```

Here we have missing fathers for individual 5 and 6. Then we add two new entries to represent the fathers that we have not seen. Thus, the dataset should be

```
fid id father mother  sex
1   1    .       .      1
1   2    .       .      2
1   3    1       2      1
1   4    1       2      1
1  100   .       .      1
1  101   .       .      1
1   5   100      2      2
1   6   101      2      1
```

where we have added two new fathers that are only used to fill out the pedigree structure. This last dataset can be read with

```
library(kinship2)
indata <- read.table("ped.txt", header=TRUE, na.strings=".")
with(indata, pedigree(id=id, dadid=father, momid=mother, sex=sex, famid=fid))
```

Now, in the fixed dataset we have made an implicit assumption that individuals 5 and 6 are half siblings and that they cannot be full siblings. If the `synbreed` package (and the relevant computations) can handle the possibility that those individuals then that is different (and computationally quite difficult) from what I suggest.